# I'm getting an error while compiling "undeclared identifier 'i'. What is the problem in my code?

Tags: c, cs50

For details, I'm learning to code by following along with harvards cs50 (2023) lecture on youtube. At timestamp 6:34:05 he is making a program called uppercase that I have followed along with. When I compile the code I get an error, but when he compiles he doesn't. What am I missing?

This code is in C.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Before: ");
    printf("After: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++);
    {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
        {
            printf("%c", s[i] - 32);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I tried to copy his code exactly and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a trailing semi-colon (`;`) after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

If compiled using `clang -Weverything test.c`, the output would be this:

```
    test.c:10:40: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++);
                                       ^
test.c:10:40: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
```

The best I could do with `gcc` (`gcc -Wall test.c`) was:

```
test.c:10:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   10 |     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++);
      |     ^~~
test.c:11:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   11 |     {
      |     ^
```

The point is, enable as many warnings as you can.  Putting a `;` at the end of the parentheses of a loop is a common source of error, though not always an error (it is in your case).  If an empty loop is desired it is customary to do the following, which `clang` recommends:

```
while(condition)
    ;
```

Comment: @ikegami it can't be known how to enable the warnings without knowing what compiler is in use

Comment: Re "*it is customary to do the following*", Or `while (cond) {}`, which is so much clearer and less error-prone

Comment: That contention, @ikegami, is subject to debate.  K&R recommended the semicolon on a line on its own.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, As opposed to placing on the same line? sure. As opposed to `{}`? It's objectively harder to see, more easy to delete as a blank line, etc.